# Почему empty говорит, что приватное свойство класса пусто, когда оно заполнено?

Tags: php, массивы, классы, рефлексия

Меня интересует вопрос по PHP, а именно работу Reflection и private свойства класса. У меня есть некий класс, у которого все приватные методы. Магический метод `__get` реализован на выдачу `return $this->$name`. Когда я в другом классе через рефлексию получаю значения приватных свойств, то `empty()` возвращает `true`, `is_array()` возвращает `true`, `count`возвращает `1` или более.

```
$reflect = new \ReflectionClass($some_class);
$props = $reflect->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $prop_name = $prop->getName();

    if (is_null($some_class->$prop_name) || empty($some_class->$prop_name)) {
        throw new \Exception(...);
    }

}
```

Класс Б

```
public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->$name;
}

public function __isset($name)
{
    return empty($this->$name);
}
```

Стандартный метод `$prop->getValue();` выдает ошибку о том, что не может обращаться не к `public` методам.

В чем прикол?

Answer (score 0):

Для использования `empty()` или `isset()` необходимо реализовывать магический метод `__isset()`

Comment: Ага, если мне надо в классе проверять на `empty`, то в основном классе надо реализовать `__isset`, но что он должен возвращать? Просто я сделал `return empty($this->$name)` (`__get` реализован), но все равно выдает `true` при обращении из другого класса. Класс А содержит `__isset` и `__get`, которые возвращают `false` (корректно), а в Классе Б при обращении `empty($some_class->$prop_name)` выдает `true` (не верно).

Comment: Во-первых, isset и empty это две разные конструкции. И реализовывать __isset через empty() - это стрелять себе в ногу. Во-вторых, не надо показывать на пальцах "я там тут написал а из другого возвращает здесь не туда". Надо написать код, и поместить его в текст вопроса.

Comment: Учел ваши замечания, выложил в пост

Comment: Не, я имел в виду полный код. Описание первого класса, описание второго класса, вызов, вывод результата. Чтобы я мог скопировать код, пойти на3v4l и выполнить его